# Proving certain properties of finite commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a finite non-zero commutative ring with unity. Then which of the following statements are necessarily true?
>
> (A) Any non-zero element of $R$ is either a unit or a zero divisor.
>
> (B) There may exist a non-zero element of $R$ which is neither a unit nor a zero divisor
>
> (C) Every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal
>
> (D) If $R$ has no zero divisors then order of any additive subgroup of $R$ has prime power order.

Clearly if $a$ is not a unit then the map $f:R \rightarrow R$ given by $f(x)=ax$ is not onto. Therefore there exists $c,d, c\neq d$ such such that

\begin{align}
& f(c)=f(d)\\
\implies & ac=ad\\
\implies & a(c-d)=0
\end{align}

Therefore $a$ is a zero divisor.

So clearly **(A) is true** and **(B) is false**.

Now if I consider $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as an example of such rings then (C) and (D) must be true but how do I prove this in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(C) follows from (A) because $R/P$ has no zero-divisors, hence only units by (A). Thus it is a field and $P$ is maximal.

(D) also follows from (A), which says that $R$ is a finite field in this case, i.e. the additive group of $R$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb F_p$-vector space and so is every subgroup.